# Inverse gait analysis using processing

Tags: processing

I am developing a code to do inverse gait analysis,that is, given the knee and hip joint angles, I am trying to recreate a walking animation on processing. But I am stuck at the maths of it.
So basically I am trying to make a stickman walk based on given lower limb joint angles.
And I for the life of it cant figure out the math.[Here is a sample of the data I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzTIk.jpg)

Comment: i am not sure i got what the question is. could you tell us what you've tried? and also if it's a math question, be sure to ask it in math stackexchange, here we focus a bit more on the code

Comment: @HarshubhMeherishi Use [Processing's Table](https://processing.org/reference/loadTable_.html) to load/parse the CSV file you would export to the data folder of your sketch, read and understand the [2D Transformations Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/): (isolating coordinate spaces using `pushMatrix()` works the same way in 3D) and of course use [`radians()`](https://processing.org/reference/radians_.html) to convert the CSV angles from degrees to radians which is what the `rotateX/Y/Z` functions expect. If you get stuck post your attempt as the simplest code snippet.